# Bookmarks to movie

Tags: bookmarks

I have two impossible questions related to movie, kindly help or give any hint/workaround:

1. Is FFmpeg able to determine bookmarks in a movie? If so, it could manipulate the movie more effectively by applying certain action on specified duration defined by bookmarks, for example, add audio started from bookmark A to B. This is much easier than using point of time
2. Is the PowerPoint able to add bookmarks then keep them after exporting to a movie?

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks are not stored with the media file, but are a function of the media player used and are usually stored in a database or similar managed and controlled by the media player.

For instance, a bookmark in VideoLAN will not be visible when playing in Windows Media Player or Media Player Classic.

As such ffmpeg would NOT see any bookmarks as they are not in the media file itself.

Comment: thanks much music2myear. So is there any means different from using timestamp, so ffmpeg could seek to a specific point?